# Referencing another link in a markdown link definition (GitLab)

Tags: gitlab, markdown

I have an `.MD` file with the following reference-style link:

```
[Test link][test-link]

[test-link]: https://google.com/
```

Is it possible to reuse the `test-link` value inside of another link?
I would like to define a base URL and build another link on top of it, meaning that `test-link-with-params` will render to `https://google.com/#search`

I imagine it working like this:

```
[Test link][test-link]
[Test link 2][test-link-with-params]

[test-link]: https://google.com/
[test-link-with-params]: [test-link]#search
```

Answer (score 0):

No I don't believe it is possible. Perhaps the best way round would be to do a sub/replace on the markdown file after you've written it.